# Outlook shows unread count of folder, but I care about total count

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2003, properties

Using Outlook 2003. I'm using the Shortcuts view on the Navigation Pane and it shows all the folders I know and love.

It shows me the number of unread items in each folder. But this is useless to me. Is it instead possible to show the total number of items in each folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the folder and then select Properties. You'll see two options:

- Show number of unread items
- Show total number of items

Select the latter, click OK and you should be done.